# Pivot table: How to show value instead of calculation

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have input data as below

```
Who|Day|Eat
Papa|Monday|Milk
Mama|Monday|Water
Papa|Friday|Bread
```

I want to get summarize table as below, I'm trying pivot table but it's not show the values, it's show count of it.

```
Name|Monday|Friday|GrandTotal
Mama|Water||1
Papa|Milk|Bread|2
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The output cannot handle adding the line `Papa|Monday|Water` in the input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to get the exact output as you'd like it using a pivot table. The two options would be:

1. Using a pivot table, but changing the format: Place the "who" and "eat" as row fields, and "Day" as the columns field. Then put either "who" or "eat" as the values field.
2. Manually building the pivot table you would like: You could manually build a pivot table using vlookup or index(match()). I would do this by creating a lookup variable (Who&Day ==> e.g. PapaMonday, PapaFriday), then doing the appropriate lookup. Let's say this lookup variable is setup before the data table (so in column A, and Who is column B, etc.). It would look something like:

Column A|Column B|Column C|Column D

Name|Monday|Friday|Grand Total

Mama | vlookup(A2&B1,sheet1!A:D,4,0) or index(sheet1!D:D,match(A2&B1,sheet1!A:A,0)) | vlookup(A2&C1,sheet1!A:D,4,0) or index(sheet1!D:D,match(A2&C1,sheet1!A:A,0)) | {Number of days}-countblank(B2:B3)

and so on and so forth. This is a pretty brute force method of doing it however.